# How to show form before completing execution of constructor in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing an application which exec(), another dialog from it.
Here problem is doing bulky task in constructor holds UI from which exec().
once constructor completes it shows form.

My question is how can i show form first and exec() constructor simultaneously.

This is how i am doing this now,

```
    Event2 ev2_obj(this);
    if(Event1::Accepted == ev2_obj.exec())
    {}
```

Comment: Better solution: don't do bulky tasks in form constructors.

Comment: Hi, if you have such a bulky task in your constructor having impact on the GUI performances (if that's what's hidden behind your question), I think you should reconsider your program and separate the heavy task in an other thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea to use `exec()` or indeed any event-loop spinning functions like `waitForXxx`. You're writing synchronous code for an inherently asynchronous system, fooling yourself in the process.

The code that executes in the GUI thread, such as `QWidget` constructors, shouldn't be doing any of the following:

- blocking file operations,
- blocking network operations,
- blocking computations.

Note that `QDialog` is-a `QWidget`. 
The example below addresses those recommendations as follows:

1. Computations and file access run in the thread pool using `QtConcurrent::run`.
2. The dialog's `accepted` and `rejected` signals are reacted to in the slots. `show()` is used instead of `exec()`.

```
class Dialog : public QDialog {
  QFuture<void> m_init;
  static void init(Dialog * dialog) {
    // do heavy initialization work here
    // You can't access any QWidget methods (and those of derived classes),
    // nor QPixmap. QImage/QPainter are OK.
    // This code should be dealing with file/network reading, computations, etc.
  }
public:
  Dialog(QWidget * parent = 0) : QDialog(parent), ... {
    // Set up child widgets etc. here
    ...
    connect(&m_watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), SIGNAL(ready()));
    m_watcher.setFuture(m_init = QtConcurrent::run(init, this));
  }
  Q_SIGNAL void ready(); // the dialog is initialized and ready for use
  bool isReady() const { return m_init.isFinished(); }
}

class DialogUser : public QWidget {
  QScopedPointer<Dialog> m_dialog;

  Q_SLOT void showDialog() {
    if (!m_dialog) {
      m_dialog.reset(new Dialog(this));
      connect(m_dialog, SIGNAL(ready()), m_dialog, SLOT(show()));
      connect(m_dialog, SIGNAL(accepted()), SLOT(dialogAccepted()));
      connect(m_dialog, SIGNAL(rejected()), SLOT(dialogRejected()));
    } else {
      if (m_dialog.isReady()) m_dialog.show();
      // otherwise the ready() signal hasn't been emitted yet and the
      // dialog will show itself
    }
  }
  Q_SLOT void dialogAccepted() {
    // react to the dialog's acceptance
    ...
  }
  Q_SLOT void dialogRejected() {
    // react to the dialog's rejection
    ...
  }
public:
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Short of having a different app that launches it's own GUI, I don;t think Qt lets you shown any GUI before the call to exec().

As other have suggested think about moving the bulky task out of the constructor.